# How to verify the order of the dropdown values in selenium webdriver 2?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie to selenium web driver. I just wanted verify the order of the dropdown values.

Eg, i have one drop down for : Service Provider.

It has 7 Values. Aircel, Airtel, BSNL, Docomo, Idea, Reliance, Vodofone. This dropdown values are sorted based on the Ascending order.

How to verify that there only 7 values and the order is correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following piece of code should help:

```
// Create expected list :: This will contain expected drop-down values
ArrayList expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList();
expectedDropDownItems.add("Aircel");
expectedDropDownItems.add("Airtel");
expectedDropDownItems.add("BSNL");
expectedDropDownItems.add("Docomo");
expectedDropDownItems.add("Idea");
expectedDropDownItems.add("Reliance");
expectedDropDownItems.add("Vodofone");

// Create a webelement for the drop-down
WebElement serviceProviderDropDownElement = driver.findElement(<locator of the drop-down e.g. By.id, By.xpath etc.>);

// Instantiate Select class with the drop-down webelement
Select serviceProviderDropDown = new Select(serviceProviderDropDownElement);

// Retrieve all drop-down values from the app and store in actual list
List<WebElement> valuesUnderServiceProviderDropDown  = serviceProviderDropDown.getOptions();

ArrayList actualDropDownItems = new ArrayList();

for(WebElement value : valuesUnderServiceProviderDropDown){
    actualDropDownItems.add(value.getText());
}

// Verify Drop-down contains ONLY 7 values
if(valuesUnderServiceProviderDropDown.size()==7)
    System.out.println("Drop-down contain exactly 7 values");

else
    System.out.println("Drop-down doesn't contain exactly 7 values");

// Compare expected and actual list
for (int i = 0; i < actualDropDownItems.size(); i++) {
    if (!expectedDropDownItems.get(i).equals(actualDropDownItems.get(i)))
    System.out.println("Drop-down values are NOT in correct order");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dropdown value count using the below code.

```
Webelement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("Dropdown Locator Value"));
Select sel = new Select(ele);
List<WebElement> list  = ele.getOptions();
System.Out.println("Drop down Value Count :" + list.size());
// To display the drop down value
for(WebElement e : list){
System.Out.println("Drop down Value :" + e.getText());
}
```

You can check the value of the drop down by comparing the retrieved value and the expected value.