# How to compare the drop down options is matching with the UI options in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

- Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver** and using **Java** for scripting.
- I have stored all drop down values of db in property file and want to compare same values whether they are in UI as in DropDown options.
- The **visualization.txt** which is in C: directory contains the below options
  **visualizationId=Day,Week,Month,Quarter,Semester,Year,RD Tech Group,ICC,Center,Software Pack,Product,Project,Customer PRs,Severity ,Priority**.

So How can I compare both values are matching. I need to get all the drop down options from property file i.e visualization.txt then need to check in the drop drop down in UI.

[image]

```
<select id="visualizationId" style="width: 120px; display: none;" name="visualization">
<option value="day">Day</option>
<option value="week">Week</option>
<option selected="" value="month">Month</option>
<option value="quarter">Quarter</option>
<option value="semester">Semester</option>
<option value="year">Year</option>
<option value="techgroup">RD Tech Group</option>
<option value="icc">ICC</option>
<option value="center">Center</option>
<option value="softwarepack">Software Pack</option>
<option value="product">Product</option>
<option value="project">Project</option>
<option value="customer">Customer PRs</option>
<option value="severity">Severity</option>
<option value="priority">Priority</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527821/how-to-verify-the-order-of-the-dropdown-values-in-selenium-webdriver-2/22530815#22530815 might help

Comment: The example which you have given is different could you please suggest few exact examples

Comment: Can you post html snippet of mentioned dropdown??

Comment: I have posted the HTML above. Please suggest me some solution

Comment: It seems to me that the link provided by mfsi_sitamj is the solution you asked for. Nobody is going to have an EXACT solution because nobody else is testing that same app. At the very least, describe which part of the solution you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following piece of code. Should help:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\visualization.txt"));
String line;
line = in.readLine();
in.close();

String[] expectedDropDownItemsInArray = line.split("=")[1].split(",");

// Create expected list :: This will contain expected drop-down values
ArrayList expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0; i<expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length; i++)
    expectedDropDownItems.add(expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i]);

// Create a webelement for the drop-down
WebElement visualizationDropDownElement = driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId"));

// Instantiate Select class with the drop-down webelement
Select visualizationDropDown = new Select(visualizationDropDownElement);

// Retrieve all drop-down values and store in actual list
List<WebElement> valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown  = visualizationDropDown.getOptions();

List<String> actualDropDownItems = new ArrayList();

for(WebElement value : valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown){
    actualDropDownItems.add(value.getText());
}

// Print expected and actual list
System.out.println("expectedDropDownItems : " +expectedDropDownItems);       
System.out.println("actualDropDownItems : " +actualDropDownItems);

// Verify both the lists having same size
if(actualDropDownItems.size() != expectedDropDownItems.size())
  System.out.println("Property file is NOT updated with the drop-down values");

// Compare expected and actual list
for (int i = 0; i < actualDropDownItems.size(); i++) {
    if (!expectedDropDownItems.get(i).equals(actualDropDownItems.get(i)))
    System.out.println("Drop-down values are NOT in correct order");
}
```

Comment: If you place **visualization.txt** under **C Drive**, You can initialize in the following way: `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\visualization.txt"));`. Edited my answer.

Comment: If suppose in UI one New options got added that is not in Property file what will happen in this case for the same code

Comment: Can you print both the list (expectedDropDownItems and actualDropDownItems) and paste the output here?

Comment: If you are NOT sure that property file is NOT updated with the drop-down items then you can first ensure that both the lists having same size, if yes then ONLY carry on with the comparison or else, fail the test there on. See Updated code for that.

Comment: so that i can show how it is printing in the result

Comment: To print both the lists just add the following lines in the code:
`System.out.println("expectedDropDownItems : " +expectedDropDownItems);
System.out.println("actualDropDownItems : " +actualDropDownItems);`

Comment: System.out.println (line); visualizationId=Day,Week,Month,Quarter,Semester,Year,RD Tech GroupICC,Center,Software Pack,Product,Project,Customer PRs,Severity,Priority

Comment: System.out.println("expectedDropDownItems : " +expectedDropDownItems); expectedDropDownItems : [Day, Week, Month, Quarter, Semester, Year, RD Tech GroupICC, Center, Software Pack, Product, Project, Customer PRs, Severity, Priority ]

Comment: System.out.println("actualDropDownItems : " +actualDropDownItems); actualDropDownItems : []
actualDropDownItems : [, ]
actualDropDownItems : [, , ]
actualDropDownItems : [, , , ] it is continuing

Comment: upto this actualDropDownItems : [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]

Comment: Use my updated code to print both the lists. Please paste the outputs here now.

Comment: If you replace 

`WebElement visualizationDropDownElement = driver.findElement("visualizationId");

Select visualizationDropDown = new Select(visualizationDropDownElement);



List<WebElement> valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown  = visualizationDropDown.getOptions();`

with

`List<WebElement> valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='visualizationId']//option"));`

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks lot you helped much But still same issue

Comment: We are targeting wrongly here then ... Can you post me an URL to the page or complete HTML code of that page? ... Now all we have to resolve is locating the drop-down correctly.

Comment: I can't post the url its offical if you see the screenshot you get to know how the dropdown will be

Comment: The problem is in Actual result i think it is not getting the values expectedDropDownItems : [Day, Week, Month, Quarter, Semester, Year, RD Tech GroupICC, Center, Software Pack, Product, Project, Customer PRs, Severity, Priority ]
actualDropDownItems : [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]

Comment: What I am guessing, there might be multiple elements present with the same id (i.e. visualizationId) in the page which are also drop-downs. Am I correct?

Comment: <div class="cell" style="margin-bottom:8px;">
<dt id="visualization-label">
<label for="visualizationId">Visualization:</label>
</dt>

Comment: <dd id="visualization-element" class="multiSelectWrapper">
<select id="visualizationId" style="width: 120px; display: none;" name="visualization">
<option value="day">Day</option>
<option value="week">Week</option>
<option selected="" value="month">Month</option>
<option value="quarter">Quarter</option>
<option value="semester">Semester</option>
<option value="year">Year</option>

Answer (score 0):

```
//Read the data from property file

String options = property.getProperty("visualizationId");

//read the options from drop down in UI
List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId"))).getOptions();
String uiOptions="";
for(WebElement eachOption : dropdownOptions ) {
   uiOptions+=eachOption.getText()+","; 
   if(!options.contains(eachOption.getText())) {
         System.out.println(eachOption.getText()+" is present in UI but not in property file");
   }
}


for(String eachOptionFromPropertyFile : options.split(",")){
   if(!uiOptions.contains(eachOptionFromPropertyFile)) {
        System.out.println(eachOptionFromPropertyFile+" is present in property file but not in UI");
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried the above answer there in the line   if(!options.contains(eachOption.getText())) { i got java.lang.NullPointerException so i changed as !uiOptions then i'm getting same error in this line for(String eachOptionFromPropertyFile : options.split(",")){

Comment: Just check whether the following command is fetching options from property file or not. If it doesn't find given key in property file it returns null as a value this might be the reason for NPE. 

String options = property.getProperty("visualizationId");