# The system cannot find the path specified in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Working on Selenium Webdriver and using Java. I'm getting error as **The system cannot find the path specified**

Code:

```
package test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
public class OEPR_DefaultTab{
private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(OEPR_DefaultTab.class.getName());
private WebDriver driver;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
Properties p= new Properties();
public Selenium selenium;

@BeforeTest
public void Login() throws Exception {
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
try {
      p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Login.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.getMessage();
    }
String url=p.getProperty("url");
DOMConfigurator.configure("src/log4j.xml");
Log.info("______________________________________________________________");
Log.info("Initializing Selenium...");

selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox",url);
Thread.sleep(5000);
Log.info("Selenium instance started");


try {
      p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Login.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.getMessage();
    }
Log.info("Accessing Stored uid,pwd from the stored text file");
String uid=p.getProperty("loginUsername");
String pwd=p.getProperty("loginPassword");
Log.info("Retrieved uid pwd from the text file");
try
{
driver.get("https://10.4.16.159/login");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Reporter.log("network server is slow..check internet connection");
    Log.info("Unable to open the website");
    throw new Error("network server is slow..check internet connection");
}
     performLogin(uid,pwd);
}  

public void performLogin(String uid,String pwd) throws Exception  
{
Log.info("Sign in to the OneReports website");
Thread.sleep(5000);
Log.info("Enter Username");
driver.findElement(By.id("loginUsername")).sendKeys(uid);
Log.info("Enter Password");
driver.findElement(By.id("loginPassword")).sendKeys(pwd); 
//submit
Log.info("Submitting login details");
waitforElement(driver,120 , "//*[@id='submit']");
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).submit();
Thread.sleep(6000);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

Log.info("Clicking on Reports link");
if(existsElement("reports")==true){

       WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("reports"));
       actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
       Thread.sleep(6000);
       }
       else{
           Log.info("element not present");
           System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");

    }
Log.info("Clicking on Extranet link");
if(existsElement("extranet")==true){

       WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("extranet"));
       actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
       Thread.sleep(6000);
       }
       else{
           Log.info("element not present");
           System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");

    }
Log.info("Clicking on PR link");
if(existsElement("ext-pr")==true){

       WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr"));
       actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
       Thread.sleep(6000);
       }
       else{ 
           Log.info("element not present");
           System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");


    }
Log.info("Clicking on Overview and Evolution PR link");
if(existsElement("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")==true){

    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution") ));
    //executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('ext-pr-backlog-evolution').style.display='block';");
    //driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")).click();
     //  WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution"));
      //actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();

      Thread.sleep(6000);
       }
       else{
           Log.info("element not present");
           System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
    }
}

//Filter selection-1


@Test()
public void Filterselection_1() throws Exception{

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/FilerSection/visualization.txt"));\\ Here i'm getting error
String line;
line = in.readLine();
in.close();

String[] expectedDropDownItemsInArray = line.split("=")[1].split(",");

// Create expected list :: This will contain expected drop-down values

ArrayList<String> expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length; i++)
    expectedDropDownItems.add(expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i]);

// Create a webelement for the drop-down
WebElement visualizationDropDownElement = driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId"));

// Instantiate Select class with the drop-down webelement
Select visualizationDropDown = new Select(visualizationDropDownElement);

// Retrieve all drop-down values and store in actual list
List<WebElement> valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown  = visualizationDropDown.getOptions();

ArrayList<String> actualDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();

for(WebElement value : valuesUnderVisualizationDropDown){
    actualDropDownItems.add(value.getText());
}

// Compare expected and actual list
for (int i = 0; i < actualDropDownItems.size(); i++) {
    if (!expectedDropDownItems.get(i).equals(actualDropDownItems.get(i)))
    System.out.println("Drop-down values are NOT in correct order");
}
}


private boolean existsElement(String id) {
try {
    driver.findElement(By.id(id));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("id is not present ");
    return false;
}

return true;
}


 private void waitforElement(WebDriver driver2, int i, String string) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@AfterTest

public void tearDown() throws Exception {
Log.info("Stopping Selenium...");
Log.info("______________________________________________________________"); 
driver.quit();
String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
  Assert.fail(verificationErrorString);
}
}
}
```

Please check the code give me some solution.
The scenario which is present in the [How to compare the drop down options is matching with the UI options in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651007/how-to-compare-the-drop-down-options-is-matching-with-the-ui-options-in-selenium/22653428?noredirect=1#comment34546546_22653428) 
For this scenario I'm trying to script. Please check the link as well.

Comment: Sorry for saying obvious but if you on windows then you should specify path to file as `C://FilerSection//visualization.txt` i.e. escape `/` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the exact text you are seeing this typically isn't a code issue - it means you need to update your PATH environment variable with the directory where java was installed.

Comment: The same path i have given try { p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/FilerSection/visualization.txt")); // p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/FilerSection/Dropdown.txt")); } catch (Exception e) { e.getMessage(); } Log.info("Accessing Stored id from the stored text file"); String id=p.getProperty("visualizationId"); Log.info("Retrieved id from the text file"); performLogin1(id);

Comment: It is exactly loading the property file. the problem i'm getting in this line BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/FilerSection/visualization.txt"));

Comment: The crazy thing about Stackexchange is that you need more reputation to comment than to answer. For the time being I have to provide answers, until I have sufficient reputation to comment :). In any case, from other posts I have seen, this error message means the PATH environment variable is wrong. It does appear however given more information that something else is going on.

Comment: @user3149905: Are you saying that you supply the same path to FileReader() and FileInputStream(), and that the latter succeeds while the former fails? Are these separate programs you are running in separate environments by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/FilerSection/visualization.txt"));
```

with

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\FilerSection\\visualization.txt"));
```

This should help.

Comment: @user11111 : Let know if you got the right answer or need more info here.